# mysql 2006 error when filtering with large list of arguments

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

Say I have a model like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
       code = models.CharField(max_length=90, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

When I have a list of codes, list_of_codes, with more than 600,000 elements and I try to get a list of codes that are in my database, I get a 'MySQL server has gone away' error on the second line below - which I think makes sense because that's when the queryset get evaluated so it's probably taking a while and the connection times out(?):

```
duplicate_codes = Order.objects.filter(code__in=list_of_codes).values_list('code', flat=True)

duplicates.update([some_dict[code] for code in duplicate_codes]) ## error gets thrown here
```

I'm trying to understand why this is happening and what would be some good ways to fix this with scalability in mind. I can't find much in the django docs about filtering with a lot of data like this. For now, I'm partitioning the list of codes and doing the filtering in chunks.

Comment: What if you use `duplicates.update([some_dict[code] for code in duplicate_codes.iterator(chunk_size=2000)])`

Comment: I've tried and that doesn't work.